# Форматирование вывода числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, float

Выполняю практику по питону с автоматической проверкой задания. Получаю следующий комментарий от безжалостной программы проверки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как будет правильнее и лучше отформатировать строку.
Если необходимо, то вот мой код

```
import math


def f(z, x):
    c = (x ** 4 - z) / (39 + ((abs(3 * z - 1 - (x ** 2 / 51)) ** 7) / 20)) - (
            (70 - 10 * math.exp(98 * z ** 2 + 30 + 12 * x) ** 2)
            / (93 * z ** 4 - 88 * (x + x ** 3 / 12 + x ** 2) ** 5)) ** 0.5
    print(c)


f(0.64, 0.71)
```

Comment: справа несколько вопросов по схожей тематике. неужели ни в одном не нашлось ответа?

Comment: К сожалению, ни в одном. Именно поэтому я и задал вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если питон достаточно свежий и можно использовать `f-строки`:

```py
print(f'{c:.2e}')
```

Т.е.:

- `.2` - 2 знака после запятой
- `e` - "научная нотация"

Да и без `f-строк` форматирование будет по тому же принципу.

Comment: Спасибо, я вместо е использовал f. Теперь я разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

```
print("{:.2e}".format(n))
```